# How to Lookup a Filtered List

Tags: excel

Is there a way to perform lookup using a table where filtering is applied and only get results that apply to that filtering?

Just to note the spreadsheet consists of 2 worksheets ("Table" and "Available"). I am looking up values in column A of "Table" against column A of "Available". Note that the VLOOKUP formula resides on the "Available" worksheet and it works correctly.

But now I have the need to apply a filter to "Table" and hope to see only results on "Available" based on that filtering.  The "Available" worksheet is still yielding results as if no filter was applied on the "Table" worksheet.

Is there a way around this to get ONLY the results that I want based on filtering?

Comment: VLOOKUP by itself does not respect filtering because table filtering is purely visual.  You can use a SUBTOTAL within a VLOOKUP to perform a VLOOKUP on visible data: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7SmU2kdt1ig